# Can the mapping storage change after contract deployment?

Tags: truffle, storage, ganache, mapping

I am beginner in mapping.I work on Truffle and Ganache. I deploy the following contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.12;
contract customerFinder{
    mapping(uint256 => address payable) public addressStorage;

    function filling(uint256 iden, address payable sender) public{
       addressStorage[iden]=sender;
    }

    function finder(uint256 id) public view returns(address payable){
       return addressStorage[id];
    }
}
```

Ganache shows the storage of the contract:

[image]

After that, i run the `filling()` function by truffle:

[image]

And a new block created. But, i expect the contract's storage be changed and no change occurrs.

[image]

Is there any problem or my expectation is false?

Comment: It says next to the mapping "not supported yet". It seems ganache UI has not implemented a way to inspect mappings, but they work in the smart contract.

Comment: What truffle version are you running?

Comment: Truffle version 5.1.8

Comment: I am also running into this problem. Not only are mappings not shown, but the entire storage-visualization seems to be broken.

Answer (score 1):

Mapping is a Key-Value storage, such that it stores a record's value as a hash. In fact, when you add a record to mapping by passing your key and value to it, mapping hashes that value. Hash is one-way, that means if one doesn't know hashing key cannot achieve the plain value . The embedded key is used to find the related hash. Finding works the way you give the key to mapping and mapping finds its corresponding hash. After that, mapping does de-hash and provides the embedded value. For this reason, Ganache cannot show you mapping's value because it has not the hashing key and can't do de-hash.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your `filling` function, and it works perfectly on my side.

However, as your mapping is public, you can access it in the same way that I'm using your `finder` function.

On my side everything is ok, maybe Ganache is not displaying this output correctly, but I tried on Remix, and I'm able to retrieve the corresponding mapped address.

Answer (score 0):

The `mapping` structure saves its index data as hash, not plain data. So no external party can see its values, even if you mention the `mapping` variable as `public`.

So the only way you can its values is to use a function such `finder` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's a bug in ganache.

From:
[https://spectrum.chat/trufflesuite/ganache/mappings-wont-show-up~31d934cd-7015-4ac3-9d35-05b4737005a2](https://spectrum.chat/trufflesuite/ganache/mappings-wont-show-up%7E31d934cd-7015-4ac3-9d35-05b4737005a2)

> sadly Ganache UI doesn't support decoding mappings right now. This is
> something we're aware of and have in mind to add, but there's a few
> technical limitations we'd have to overcome for that to be possible.